# if $ f(x)=x+\cos x $ then find $ \int_0^\pi (f^{-1}(x))\text{dx} $?

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I would be interest to show :

if $ f(x)=x+\cos x $  then find $ \int_0^\pi (f^{-1}(x))\text{dx} $ ?

my  second question that's make me  a problem is that :

what is :$ f^{-1}(\pi) $ ?

I would be interest for any replies or any comments .

Comment: It looks like $f^{-1}(\pi)$ will be hard to find (see here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%20%3D%20x%20%2B%20cos%28x%29&t=ff3tb01)

Comment: pleas , Almost machine give us :$ f^{-1}(\pi)\approx 3.88068 $, i seek for nice  way of computing  $a$ and $b $if we look to use this formula  : $\int_a^b\! f(x)\, dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)\, dx = bf(b)-af(a). $

Comment: The equation for $f^{-1}(\pi)$ is a [trancendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) which are notoriously hard to solve and in many cases its impossible to find closed form solutions in terms of elementary functions. This is (most likely) one such case so I'd stick with a numerical value if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=\pi$. Then $f$ is monotonically increasing and (hence) one-one on the interval $[a,b]$. So to get the integral consider the rectangle formed by $[0,b] \times [0,\pi]$. Then 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}f^{-1}(x) \, dx & = \pi b- \int_{a}^{b} x + \cos x \, dx\\
& = \pi b- \left(\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}\right) + \left(\sin b -\sin a\right)\\
\end{align*} 
So all you need is the value of $a$ and $b$ which can be obtained numerically.

Answer (score 2):

There is something questionable in the wording (about the bounds of the integral). So, two interpretations are presented below :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)}f^{-1}(x)dx=bf(b)-af(a)$$

$$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}(x+\cos x)dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}f^{-1}(x)dx=b\pi$$
$$ f(b)=\pi\Rightarrow b+\cos b=\pi\Rightarrow b\approx 3.88$$
$$f(a)=0\Rightarrow a+\cos a=0\Rightarrow a\approx -0.74$$
$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}f^{-1}(x)dx=b\pi-\frac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{2}+(\sin( b)-\sin(a))$$